# How to search filters when a tag contains parentheses

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, boto3, aws-cli

I have some EC2s and EBS snapshots that are tagged. I want to be able to search for those AWS objects based on the value of those tags. However, some of the tags' values contain strings with parenthesised elements. Queries issued through the aws-cli, the Powershell SDK and even the web UI all seem to choke when the queried-for tag-value contains parenthesised elements

I've tried various iterations of slash-escaping the parenthesis:

- `\(`
- `\\(`
- `\\\(`

Only tried the multiple-slash ones because some other API interfaces have wanted them when doing embedded JSON payloads (translation: I was grasping at straws).

Using:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters \
  "Name=tag:Snapshot Group,Values=YYYMMDDHHMM (<OWNING_INSTANCE_ID>)"
```

Returns a null-set (same when using equivalent queries in the PowerShell SDK, boto3 and even the web console), whereas using:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters \
  "Name=tag:Snapshot Group,Values=YYYMMDDHHMM *(<OWNING_INSTANCE_ID>)*"
```

Returns the desired list of objects in the AWS CLI (but returns an unpredictable-list with the PowerShell SDK and the web console)

Seems like there should be a way to escape the parentheses rather than having to introduce a neighboring-wildcard into the query-string.

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html#Filtering_Resources_CLI, it is  `\ ` that is required to escape special chars in the CLI, though parentheses aren't mentioned as such.
Why is `(<OWNING_INSTANCE_ID>)` not prefixed by a field name such as `Name=`? The [`aws ec2 describe-snaphost`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html) show no _positional_ arguments, from what I can tell. Can you show an example of where use of the PowerShell SDK returns an unpredictable list, and what do you mean by unpredictable?

Comment: Basically, I was programatically-generating a (set of) snapshot(s), then applying a tag named `Snapshot Group` to the resultant snapshot(s). I was setting a value for the `Snapshot Group` tag that worked out to the above type of pattern. Which is to say, if the EBS were owned by instance-id `i-d955bd02d4ef7` and I was generating the snapshot today, the resultant tag-value would have been `201909121731 (i-d955bd02d4ef7)`

Comment: Currently, my Windows test-instance is offline (was working with boto3 on Linux, today, and wasn't expecting such a speedy response to my question).

That said, yesterday, I was finding that if I had (again) a tag-value of `201909121731 (i-d955bd02d4ef7)`, that if I changed that `f7` to, say, `fz`, it would still return the `f7` snapshots if I included `*(i-d955bd02d4ef7)*` in my filter.

Comment: I see; a shot in the dark: perhaps the values that contain _spaces_ need _embedded quoting_.

Comment: THANKS! That was exactly it:

`aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters
  "Name=tag:Snapshot Group,Values='201909102029 (i-d955bd02d4ef7)'"` 

Got me the results I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion by @mklement0:

When parentheses are present in a tag value, I need to add *internal quoting* (single quotes if the external quoting uses double quotes; double quotes if the external quoting uses single quotes); e.g.:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters "Name=tag:Snapshot Group,Values='201909102029 (i-d955bd02d4ef7)'"
```

Comment: Spaces didn't *seem* to make a difference, but the parenthese sure as heck did: they're apparently used as a search-term grouper much like when constructing an LDAP query.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.